# Read single standard UTF-8 string from InputStream in Java

Tags: java, c#, utf-8, stream

There is a stream of serialized C# objects (String fields use standard UTF-8). I'm reading the stream and deserializing it in Java (one object at a time). Java uses MUTF-8 format for the string. DataInputStream.readUTF assumes that format. Is there a way to read just one single "standard" UTF-8 string from input stream?

Comment: What exactly is `one single "standard" UTF-8 string`? Also: serialized C#-objects will have some stuff around their string fields, are you prepared to do some parsing?

Comment: If you have control over it, you're probably better off doing the serialization to a language neutral format, like say xml or json

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The objects I'm deserializing contains a String field. I'm reading one field at a time from the stream. readLong, readShort etc. I wanted to know how to read the UTF-8 string field from the stream.

I do not have control over the serialization part.

Comment: I tried a few ways, BufferedReader, Apache commons-io IOUtils etc. But they all assume that the entire stream is UTF-8 strings. I just want to read enough bytes from the stream, which represent a valid standard UTF-8 string. I'm looking into if I can change the serialization to deal with this issue.